# azure log search alerts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have this search but I want to azure alert when the bandwidth reaches 50%. I have tried the alert setup but that only set how many times the search found. so not sure what needs to be add on search only triggers the bandwidth threshold.

```
AzureMetrics
      | where ResourceId contains "ckt"
      | where MetricName == "BitsINPerSecond"
      | where TimeGenerated > (now() - 12h) and TimeGenerated <= now()
      | project TimeGenerated, Resource, inBytes=Maximum
      | join kind= inner
       (
       AzureMetrics
      | where MetricName == "BitsOutPerSecond"
      | where TimeGenerated > (now() - 12h) and TimeGenerated <= now()
       | project TimeGenerated, Resource, outBytes= Maximum
      )
      on TimeGenerated, Resource
      | summarize data_in_Gbps = max(inBytes)/1000000000, data_out_Gbps = max(outBytes)/1000000000, 
       data_total_Gbps = sum(inBytes + outBytes)/1000000000 by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Resource
      | extend BW_percentage = data_out_Gbps * 100
      | order by TimeGenerated
```

Comment: It is not clear from the question if: (a) your query is working as expected and you are asking how to use it in Azure Alerts, or (b) your query is not working as expected and you are looking to to fix it. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for response. the query is working to display the current usage but I want this query to send me an alert when the bandwidth reaches above threshold 50% for 30 minutes. What query need to add to generate alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in the end of the query : "|where BW_percentage>50".
Check that you are happy with the results when you run the query yourself.
Then copy the query to the alert rule and set the threshold to >0 to alert you on any one resource where this is true.
(You can change the 1h to 30m if this is the time span that interest you).